# NoSuchMethodError exception when read the protobuf file from HDFS

Tags: java, hdfs, protocol-buffers

I am writing a java program to count line of protobuff file stored in HDFS and execute the program with "hadoop -jar countLine.jar"

However, I get the exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.shouldDiscardUnknownFields()Z at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessageV3.java:290)

This only happens on some of the protobuf files. Files with different schema does not have this issue.

My protobuf file is gzipped pb.gz.

```
//Here is the code 
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path path = new Path(<HDFS path to file>);
InputStream input = new GZIPInputStream(fs.open(path));
Message m;
while ((m = defaultMsg.getParserForType().parseDelimitedFrom(input)) != null) {
                recordCount++;
}
```

If I put the file in local, everything works fine

```
InputStream input = new GZIPInputStream(new File(path_to_local_file));
Message m;
while ((m = defaultMsg.getParserForType().parseDelimitedFrom(input)) != null) {
                recordCount++;
}
```

Does anyone have idea. Will the file size cause this issue?

Thanks

David

Comment: Every time I've run into a NoSuchMethodError, it's been because of a version conflict in a library I'm using. Usually I have a direct dependency, and an indirect dependency, and they aren't using the same version. I can't say that's the only reason this can happen, but it's the first place I would look.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jwismar for the hints.
The issue happens when I run the "hadoop jar countLine.jar" from command line. Hadoop classloader loads protobuf library came with it which has lower version than the protoc that I used to generate the java files. Once I down grade the protoc to lower version and re-generate the java files, the issue is gone.

Thanks
David